# Ray library throws "setpgrp failed" error

Tags: python-3.7, ray

I am the new with Ray library, when I execute it, I caught some errors

```
import ray
# Start Ray. If you're connecting to an existing cluster, you would use
# ray.init(address=<cluster-address>) instead.
ray.init()
```

Error:

> 2019-12-30 09:39:42,656    WARNING services.py:597 -- setpgrp failed, processes may not be cleaned up properly: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted.

I think because of this error so when i run my code, my kernel will die.

```
# Execute Python functions in parallel.
import ray
ray.init()

@ray.remote
def f(x):
    return x * x

futures = [f.remote(i) for i in range(4)]
print(ray.get(futures))
```

Comment: what happens if you do what the comment says?

Comment: my kernel will die after a little bit sir! Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: you did not answer my question

Comment: sorry sir, if i run what the comment says, nothing will happen but when i run these codes under, my kernel will die after few seconds.
Thank for your reply

Comment: @BuiNgocBao Maybe you can refer: https://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/6718